# Negative coordinates in a grid based game

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, game-engine, path-finding

I have written a small 2D game in javascript that uses a grid where the player starts at position [0,0] and can move an almost infinite distance in either direction.

Now I want to implement A* pathfinding, but I'm having some problems finding the best way to store the world with all it's different obstacles, enemies and terrain. This is what I have tried or thought about so far.

**Array of arrays**

Here I store the world in an array of arrays `[x][y]`.

```
var world = [[]];
world[312][11] = 0;
world[312][12] = 0;
world[312][13] = 1;
world[312][14] = 1;
...
```

This works great with A* pathfinding! It's easy and very fast to access a specific coordinate and populate the world. In the example above I just store passable (0) or impassable (1) terrain, but I can store pretty much whatever I want there. However, this doesn't work very well with negative coordinates like if my players is at `[-12][-230]`. Negative keys in a javascript array isn't actually part of the array, they won't be included in `world.length` or `world[3].length` and from what I understand, it's overall bad practice and might have some impact on the performance as well. I read somewhere that if you are using negative keys in your array, you are doing it wrong.
I would still not pass the entire world into the A* function for obvious reasons. Just a small part close to my player, but the coordinates would correspond to the positions in the array which is easy to work with.

**A separate array of arrays just for A* pathfinding**

This is where I'm at right now. I have a separate 50x50 grid called `pathMap = [[]]`, that is **only** used for pathfinding.

```
var pathMap = [[]];
pathMap[0][0] = 0;
pathMap[0][1] = 0;
pathMap[0][2] = 1;
pathMap[0][3] = 1;
...
```

It starts at `pathMap[0][0]` and goes to `pathMap[50][50]` and is working as an overlay on my current position where I (as the player) will always be in the center position. My *real* coordinates may be something like `[-5195,323]`, but it translates to `pathMap[25][25]` and everything close to me is put on the pathMap in relation to my position.
Now this works, but it's a huge mess. All the translations from one coordinate to another back and forth makes my brain hurt. Also, when I get the path back from A*, I have to translate each step of it back to the actual position my element should move to in the real world. I also have to populate the same object into 2 different grids every update which hurts performance a bit as well.

**Array of objects**

I think this is where I want to be, but I have some issues with this as well.

```
var world = [];
world[0] = { x: -10, y: 3, impassable: 0 };
world[1] = { x: -10, y: 4, impassable: 0 };
world[2] = { x: -10, y: 5, impassable: 1 };
world[3] = { x: -10, y: 6, impassable: 1 };
...
```

Works great with negative x or y values! However, it's not as easy to find for instance `[10,3]` in this array. I have to loop through the entire array to look for an object where `x == 10` and `y == 3` instead of the very easy and fast approach `world[10][3]` in the first example. Also, I can't really rely on the coordinates being in the right order using this version, sorting becomes harder, as does other things that was a lot easier with the array of arrays.

**Rebuild the game to always be on the positive side**

I would prefer not to do this, but I have considered placing the players starting position at something like `[1000000,1000000]` instead, and making negative coordinates off limits. It seems like a failure if I have to remove the vision I have of endlessness just to make the pathfinding work with less code. I know there will always be some upper or lower limits anyways, but I just want to start at [0,0] and not some arbitrary coordinate for array related reasons.

**Other?**

In javascript, is there another option that works better and is not described above? I'm very open to suggestions!

Is there a best practice for similar cases?

Comment: Would it work if you make world an Object with key being `X;Y`: `world = {}; world['-10;-10'] = 0`? Or make objects of objects, so `world[10][10]` would work kind of like an array.

Comment: Interesting! Like the *array of objects* version with the simplicity to find a specific coordinate of the *array of arrays*. I kinda like it, but it feels dirty for some reason. I guess it's the concatenation and splitting of the key that puts me off a bit.

Comment: `world = {}; world[-10] = {}; world[-10][-10] = 0`. You'd have to maintain your own `length` property, and `Array.prototype` methods (if you need anything like `forEach` on your `world`). That could be done at generation or with custom method to add coordinate to `world`, or with setters/getters. I don't think there would be much penalty performance-wise compared to `Array[Array]`, since arrays are basically objects with different prototypes.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is exactly what is already happening if I try to add a negative key to an array. It creates what you are describing. The biggest issue I have with that is that there is no guarantee that the order will be maintained, aside from the fact that I would have to rewrite a bunch of array functionality, but that I was already prepared to do. But I will explore your option a bit more I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three coordinates system you must distinguish :

- the world coordinates.
- the world model / path-finding (array) coordinates.
- the screen coordinates.

The screen coordinates system depends upon :

- the viewport = the canvas. (width, height in pixels).
- a camera     = (x,y) center in world coordinates + a viewWidth (in world coordinates).

To avoid headaches, build a small abstraction layer that will do the math for you.

You might want to use Object.defineProperty to define properties, that will provide a fluent interface.

```
var canvas = ... ;
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeigth = canvas.heigth;


var world = {
              width  : 1000,  // meters
              height : 1000,  // meters
              tileSize : 0.5,   // height and width of a tile, in meter
              model  : null,  // 2D array sized ( width/tileSize, XtileSize )
             };
// possibles world coordinates range from -width/2 to width/2 ; - height/2 height/2.

 var camera = {
                 x : -1,
                 y : -1,
                 viewWidth : 10, // we see 10 meters wide scene
                 viewHeight : -1 // height is deduced from canvas aspect ratio
              };
camera.viewHeight = camera.viewWidth * canvasWidth / canvasHeight ;
```

Then your character looks like :

```
// (x,y) is the center of the character in centered world coordinates
// here (0,0) means (500,500) world coords
//                  (1000,1000) array coords
//                  (320, 240) screen coords in 640X480
function /*Class*/ Character(x, y) {
     var _x=x;
     var _y=y;
     var _col=0;
     var _row=0;
     var _sx=0.0;
     var _sy=0.0;         
     var dirty = true;
     Object.defineProperty(this,'x', 
                              { get : function() {return _x; } 
                                set : function(v) { _x=v; 
                                                    dirty=true; } });
     Object.defineProperty(this,'x', 
                              { get : function() {return _y; } 
                                set : function(v) { _y=v; 
                                                    dirty=true; } });
     Object.defineProperty(this,'col', 
                              { get : function() {
                                               if (dirty) updateCoords();
                                               return _col; }  });
     Object.defineProperty(this,'row', 
                              { get : function() {
                                               if (dirty) updateCoords();
                                               return _row; }  });
     Object.defineProperty(this,'sx', 
                              { get : function() {
                                               if (dirty) updateCoords();
                                               return _sx; }  });
     Object.defineProperty(this,'sy', 
                              { get : function() {
                                               if (dirty) updateCoords();
                                               return _sy; }  });
     function updateCoords() {
        _row = ( ( _x + 0.5 * world.width )/ world.tileSize ) | 0 ;
        _col = ( ( _x + 0.5 * world.height )/ world.tileSize ) | 0 ;
        _sx =  canvasWidth  * ( 0.5 + ( _x - camera.x ) / camera.viewWidth ) ;
        _sy =  canvasHeight * ( 0.5 + ( _y - camera.y ) / camera.viewHeight ) ;
        dirty = false;            
     }
}
```

Comment: This was a fantastic clarification of my *"A separate array of arrays just for A pathfinding"*-option that I'm already using. It seems it's just a matter of accepting that I'm working with several different coordinate systems and making it work.